# Sqlite INSERT INTO ... SELECT using ORDER BY

Tags: sqlite

I have a table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRACE_TABLE ([TRACE_NUM] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY [TRACE_ID] INTEGER NOT NULL [TRACE_TIME_DELTA] TEXT NOT NULL [TRACE_TIME_HEX] INTEGER NOT NULL [TRACE_TIME_AHB] INTEGER NOT NULL [TRACE_PARAM_TEXT] TEXT NOT NULL [TRACE_PARAM_TEXT_DECODED] TEXT);
```

Now I want to sort this table using a column. To do this I do following:

1. Create a new table **TRACE_TABLE_TEMP** using above statement if not exists.
2. Then delete all rows (in case any exists) by earlier operations
3. Then copy all rows from **TRACE_TABLE** to **TRACE_TABLE_TEMP** but in *sorted order using a column*.

I try to execute the statement in Sqlite DB browser but I am not getting the expected result. Please see below, the **TRACE_NUM** column is *not sorted as DESC*.

[image]

How do I copy the table to another in sorted order?

Comment: You don’t have an `ORDER BY` clause in your last `SELECT`. The database can return the results in any order then. They don’t have any inherent order by default. They may be inserted in order but that doesn’t define how they’re returned.

Comment: why are runing three queries all at the time

Comment: I dont have a ORDER BY in my last statement because I expected that second statement would copy ROWS in sorted order.

Comment: I am running 3 queries back to back to show the operations after that I expect the rows to be copied in sorted order but its not :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) says:

> If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is undefined.

So it does not make much sense to change the order in which rows are stored, because you'd have to put the same ORDER BY on the queries used to read the data later.

Anyway, the error is that `'TRACE_NUM'` is a constant string. To refer to the contents of the column, use `TRACE_NUM`.